# Scope of do-while loop?

Tags: java, scope

In Java, the body of a `do-while` loop and the loop condition do not belong to the same scope. So the following code won't compile:

```
do {
    boolean b = false;
} while (b); // b cannot be resolved to a variable
```

But this code does make sense to me.

Also, I cannot find any pitfalls if the body and the condition are in the same scope; since the body will always get executed, and Java does not have `Goto`, I don't know how a variable declaration in the outermost `do-while` body scope could be skipped. Even if it is possible, the compiler could always detect such possibility and then produce compile time errors.

Is there any reason for this behavior (aside from keeping the `do-while` loop in the same format as `while`)? I am really curious. Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: I think it's because the scope in Java goes by block `{}`.

Comment: Scope in Java is clearly delineated by curly braces.  Notice that the while(b) is outside the curly braces and boolean b is inside.  That puts them in different scopes.

Comment: Can you use extraneous `{}` in Java like you can in C/C++ then?

Comment: (Although I'd add that if you're using extra `{}` to create blocks you're probably doing it wrong, and things should be refactored instead.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's one way scope is defined in Java; inside `{}` is a new scope.

IMO it wouldn't make much sense to special-case a single construct.

Comment: So there's no real problem aside from the general rules? I need to look into the spec now:)

Comment: @ZiyaoWei It's not a problem, just not what you expected :)

Comment: Java does not always define scope with {}.  For example the code "for (int z=0;z<10;z++) {}" defines z outside the {} but its scope is different from the block that contains the for loop.  I agree with OP that it would be better if Java bent the {} scoping rules for do-while loops so the do-while can terminate on a variable that does not pollute the outer block's namespace.  But it's too late to make that change in Java now.

Comment: @AdamGawne-Cain That doesn't change that inside `{}` is a new scope, specific to the OP's question. That said: the scope of `for` loop variables are explicitly executed as a local variable declaration within a block; the scope of those var decls is precisely the same as if it were declared within a block. (And must be, since a for-loop's statement may not be a block statement). But I'll tweak the wording.

Answer (score 16):

Following your logic here is the case when `b` would not be defined prior to first usage:

```
do {
    continue;
    boolean b = false;
} while (b); // b cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Note that very often `boolean` flags are a code smell, try to avoid them rather than fight with them.

Comment: I doubt if this is the real problem? If this is a while loop then the compiler complains about "unreachable code", but since this is a do-while loop the compiler just complains about b not being declared, but I imagine the compiler would just do the same if the do-while is a single scope. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the real problem is that the scope of a variable is limited to the `{}` block where it was declared. Period. I just wanted to show you that even if this was not the case, it is possible to reach `while` condition without `b` being defined.

Comment: The compiler cannot give a warning about "unreachable code" if there is an `if` statement and `continue` is in the then part.

Comment: I just hate to receive downvotes without explanation. If I am wrong please correct me, I also want to learn something here :-).

Comment: I liked the example; +1 for me.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good example. If the compiler were to allow variables declared in the `do` block to appear in the `while` block, then it would do control flow analysis, like it does with every variable, find that `b` is potentially undefined at a use, and complain. This answer does not give a good reason that disallowing this case means that something like `do { int x = something(y); } while (x != 0)` should also be disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the boolean variable `b` is scoped to the body of the `do..while` loop.  Since the conditional check is executed outside the body, the variable is out of scope.  The correct construct would be:

```
boolean b = false ; // Or whichever initial value you want
do {
    b = false;
} while (b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this if you want exit do-while block while boolean defined inside of do-while block.

```
do{
  boolean b;
  ...
  if(b){
    break;
  }
}while(otherCondition)  //or while(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    boolean b = false;
}
while (b);
```

Because the boolean variable `b` is a local variable having scope only within a [**block**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#246838).

From the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#5920):

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by
>   a block.

Answer (score 0):

It is basic scope rules. Variables declared inside a set of curly braces {} go out of scope at the end of the braces. It defeats the standard scope rules and it would be extra work for the compiler to detect such a case.

Answer (score 0):

**The statement definition and your variable are not visible** outside your statement block `{}`, which is why the compiler complains.

The difference between the `while` and `do ... while` is that the `do ... while` is guaranteed to execute at least once and that is a more simpler way to write according to the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html)

Regarding scope of a variable, it has to be visible, according to [these rules](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#32644) or else you get a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DoWhileLoopExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Do While Loop Example");

        } while(i<1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: Avoid overt self-promotion. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising)