# How do I add the distances in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am supposed to add the distance of a walker's position after N steps. I run the while T times and need to add all of the N steps after T trails and divide by the amount of trials to get an average. This is my code so far. Iv tried doing a different integer like distance/T but it says that distance isn't found. Is that because it is defined in the while loop. I am using processing.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Steps");
int x=Integer.parseInt(input);
if (x<0)
{
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid Entry.");
}
int T=1;
int N=0;
while (T<10)
{
    while (N<x)
    {
        int stepsX=Math.round(random(1,10));
        int stepsY=Math.round(random(1,10));
        System.out.println(stepsX+","+stepsY);
        N=N+1;
        if (N==x)
        {
            int distance=(stepsX*stepsX)+(stepsY*stepsY);
            System.out.println(distance);
        }
    }
    T=T+1;
    N=0;
}
System.out.println("mean sq. dist = ");
```

Comment: First thing to do: fix your indentation. If your code is *really* like that in whatever editor you're using, that's making your life a lot harder. If it's actually indented properly in the editor but you haven't bothered doing so here - that's making *our* lives a lot harder.

Comment: I edited your nightmare code, but would you mind rephrasing your question a little better.

Comment: Yes, take the time to produce good indentation.  Most editors will help you.  And when you paste something here, take care to check that the indentation is preserved.  This is probably more important than getting your pointer notation right.

Comment: Yes I do apologize for my indentation. I am really new to programming so I am still learning the format. I don't know how to add the distance of each trail when N=x (ie int distance). I need to add each distance from each trail of T.

Comment: @user2770061 What is a "trail" of T?

Comment: since there are two while loops, trail of T is just the run through of T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because you're not keeping track of total distance.  Also, your `distance` int variable only exists in the scope:

```
        if (N==x)
        {
            int distance=(stepsX*stepsX)+(stepsY*stepsY);
            System.out.println(distance);
        }
```

Read more about scopes here:  [Scope of do-while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068814/java-scope-of-do-while-loop)

It's kind of unclear what you need, but here is some changes I made that I think will help:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Steps");
int x=Integer.parseInt(input);
if (x<0)
{
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid Entry.");
}
int T=1;
int N=0;
double totalDistance = 0.0;//keep track over over distance;
while (T<10)
{
    while (N<x)
    {
        int stepsX=Math.round(random(1,10));
        int stepsY=Math.round(random(1,10));
        System.out.println(stepsX+","+stepsY);
        N=N+1;
        if (N==x)
        {
            int distance=(stepsX*stepsX)+(stepsY*stepsY);
            totalDistance = totalDistance + distance;
            System.out.println("current distance:  " + distance);
            System.out.println("current total distance:  " + totalDistance);
        }
    }
    T=T+1;
    N=0;
}
//calculate whatever you need using totalDistance
System.out.println("mean sq. dist = " + (totalDistance/T) );
```

Comment: This was helpful. I just need to add a different int like how you had it in this code. Sorry for the confusion. I will try to be more precise in my notation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my answer, you seem to be loosing all of your steps except last one in a while loop.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Steps");
int x=Integer.parseInt(input);
if (x<0)
{
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid Entry.");
}
int T=1;
int N=0;
int stepsX = 0;
int stepsY = 0;
while (T<10)
{
    while (N<x)
    {
        stepsX += Math.round(random(1,10));
        stepsY += Math.round(random(1,10));
        System.out.println(stepsX+","+stepsY);
        N=N+1;
        if (N==x)
        {
            int distance=(stepsX*stepsX)+(stepsY*stepsY);
            System.out.println(distance);
        }
    }
    T=T+1;
    N=0;
}
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stepsX, 2) + Math.pow(stepsY, 2));
System.out.println("mean sq. dist = "+distance);
```

But please if it is not rephrase your question.