# Grade calculator won't execute while loop

Tags: java, do-while

I have an assignment for class that requires us to take input from the user, drop the lowest assignment grade, then take a few more grades, calculate the average. I've got all that done but the last step is we must ask the user if they want to repeat the program for another student. The `do while` loop I have won't execute.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateGrades{
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    double score;
    double sum=0;
    double lowest=100;

    do{
        //ASSIGNMENT GRADES
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println("enter grade for assignment " +i);
            score=sc.nextDouble();
            sum=sum+score;

            if(score<lowest){
                lowest=score;
            }
        }
        sum=sum-lowest;
        double assignmentAvg= sum/4;
        System.out.println("After the lowest grade is dropped, your assignment average is " + assignmentAvg);

        //EXAM GRADES
        System.out.println("enter grade for exam one");
        double exam1=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter grade for exam two");
        double exam2=sc.nextDouble();

        //LAB GRADE
        System.out.println("enter grade for lab");
        double lab= sc.nextDouble();

        //FINAL EXAM GRADE
        System.out.println("enter grade for final exam");
        double Final=sc.nextDouble();

        //AVERAGE
        double avg= (assignmentAvg*.2)+(exam1*.15)+(exam2*.2)+(lab*.2)+(Final*.25);

        if(avg >=90){
            System.out.println("Your weighted average is " + avg + " and your letter grade is A");
        }
        else if(avg >=80){
            System.out.println("Your weighted average is " + avg + " and your letter grade is B");
        }
        else if(avg >=70){
            System.out.println("Your weighted average is " + avg + " and your letter grade is C");
        }
        else if(avg >=60){
            System.out.println("Your weighted average is " + avg + " and your letter grade is D");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your weighted average is " + avg + " and your letter grade is F");
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate for another student? Press 1 for yes, or any key to terminate");
        int again= sc.nextInt();

    }while(again==1);

    // for next student reset sum
}
}
```

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: the entire purpose of a do...while loop is to run at least once...

Comment: Don't forget to set `sum` back to zero before you run with the next student.

Comment: As I don't see an `again` outside the `do-while` loop, I don't see how this can even compile, let alone run. Also, **please don't break the code into multiple short lines when it originally was not that way.** It's OK to let the code run into long lines, as long as the syntax highlighting is correct and it is legible.

Comment: looks like a potential scope issue, declare `again` outside of your while loop.

Comment: @ADTC  I guess "won't execute" is a necessary consequence of "won't compile".

Comment: @DavidWallace "won't execute" is more of a blanket statement. It's like saying "My computer doesn't work." *What exactly does it mean? Doesn't boot up? Boots up but crashes? Boots up fine but doesn't do what you want it to do?*

Comment: You may want to use something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Javaprogramtodemonstratemenuselection.htm) for bonus points.

Comment: declare again outside do while 'int again=0;'

Answer (score 0):

Your `again` variable is out of scope. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068814/java-scope-of-do-while-loop).  Fix is to declare `again` before the loop.