how can I compare a string in a do-while loop from switch case
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WorkArea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String errorMessage="Invalid input entered. Terminating...";
        
        do {
        System.out.println("Operations: add subtract multiply");
        System.out.println("Enter an operation:");
        String operation=input.next();

        switch(operation.toLowerCase())
        {
        case "add":
            System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {
                int int1=input.nextInt();
                    if(input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        int int2=input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Answer:"+(int1+int2));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
            }else{
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
            }
            break;
        case "subtract":
            System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {
                int int1=input.nextInt();
                    if(input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        int int2=input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Answer:"+(int1-int2));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
            }else{
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
            break;
        case "multiply":
            System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
            if(input.hasNextDouble())
            {
                double double1=input.nextDouble();
                    if(input.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                        double double2=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.printf("Answer:%.2f\n",double1*double2);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
            }else{
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
            break;
        
        default:
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            break;
        }
    }while(!operation.equals("add")||!operation.equals("subtract")||!operation.equals("multiply"));
}
}

I have tried do-while loop to function the operations as I have listed in the snippet repeatedly by comparing the string from the switch case. I am expecting the program should terminate if the operation is out of the list.
while(!operation.equals("add")||!operation.equals("subtract")||!operation.equals("multiply"));
while(!operation=="add"||"subtract"||"multiply");
while(!operation.equals("multiply"));

when I compare the string using do-while loop the result says "operation cannot be resolved".
How can I perform multiple operations using do-while loop in a single console window

Change String operation=input.next(); to operation=input.next(); and add String operation; before the do {. The variable operation is out of scope at }while (!operation.equals ....  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068814/scope-of-do-while-loop and others.

operation needs to be defined outside of your loop, otherwise it is out of scope. Also, while(!operation.equals("add")||!operation.equals("subtract")||!operation.equals("multiply")) is always true, you want to use && here

The question is closed as a duplicate, as it should be. But, the close notice has the wrong duplicate. The issue here is scope of variables. String comparison in the code is not an issue here.

Variables defined inside a loop will have block scope, ie, they can only be used inside the loop body.
In your code, the operation variable can only be used inside the loop body.
Modifying your program -
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WorkArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        String errorMessage="Invalid input entered. Terminating...";
        String operation = null;

        do {
        System.out.println("Operations: add subtract multiply");
        System.out.println("Enter an operation:");
        operation=input.next();

        switch(operation.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "add":
                System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
                if(input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    int int1=input.nextInt();
                    if(input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        int int2=input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Answer:"+(int1+int2));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
                break;
            case "subtract":
                System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
                if(input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    int int1=input.nextInt();
                    if(input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        int int2=input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Answer:"+(int1-int2));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
                break;
            case "multiply":
                System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
                if(input.hasNextDouble())
                {
                    double double1=input.nextDouble();
                    if(input.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                        double double2=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.printf("Answer:%.2f\n",double1*double2);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
                break;
        }
    }while(!operation.equals("add")||!operation.equals("subtract")||!operation.equals("multiply"));


From the above program I get "operation detection with case sensitivity at the run time, if I change the line into  System.out.println("Enter an operation:");
operation=input.next().toLowerCase(); Why do I get the same run time Error. Thanks

@PriyadhanamPriyadhanam  I don't understand the context for ""operation detection with case sensitivity".  Could you, please, clear that up?  But, you should note, in addition to the variable scope issue, there is a logic bug: Please see the comment from QBrute in the comments below the question.
